# Create custom numeric arrays index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typeof

I trying a creation of insulted index in Javascript. That´s my code.

```
var map = [];

function createIndexIfNotExists (posx,posy){            
if(typeof(map[posx]===undefined)){
            map[posx] = {};
            console.log("created: map["+posx+"] typeof="+typeof(map[posx])); //typeof object
}

if(typeof(map[posx][posy]===undefined)){
            map[posx][posy] = [];
            console.log("created: map["+posx+"]["+posy+"] 
typeof="+typeof(map[posx])); //typeof object 
}
map[posx][posy].push( {'posx':posx, 'posy':posy }); }

createIndexIfNotExists(10,5);
createIndexIfNotExists(10,6);
```

But the result is this.

```
created: map[10] typeof=object
created: map[10][5] typeof=object
created: map[10] typeof=object
created: map[10][6] typeof=object
```

Why create `map[10]` two times if typeof is `object` and not `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

On this line you need to move the `()`

`if(typeof(map[posx]===undefined)){`

should be:

`if(typeof(map[posx])===undefined){`

The same is true for this line:

`if(typeof(map[posx][posy])===undefined){`

You're finding the type of the comparison which will always evaluate to the string `'boolean'` which will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` return the tyoe as a string, so the type checking will be like

```
if(typeof(map[posx])==="undefined")
```

and

```
if(typeof(map[posx][posy])==="undefined")
```

and also the `(` and `)` is not required in `typeof` to wrap the item you are going to check, its a `keyword`, nit a `function`. when you are wrapping an expression (`map[posx]===undefined` in your case) wit `()` in typeof that meant the preference of executing that expression is higher, and type will be checked upon that result. so the expression resolved `map[posx]===undefined` resolved first and you are checking the type of the resule `true` or `false`